# Adding a Custom Search API in spree commerce application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, spree

Please pardon if the question is a bit too lame, I have no experience with either Ruby or Rails.

I have an existing Spree Commerce application and I am implementing an integration with a third party to provide search result.

The Third party has given us API's and my job is to modify the existing install of spree and use the API to display result.

Please suggest the best way to proceed with this. I am actually unsure where to start. 
The possible way which I see is to build a Spree Extension, but I am unsure as to how am I supposed to override the existing search implementation in this extension. I have read about Deface but that doesn't exactly solve my problem.
This extension shouldn't modify the existing UI.

Any kind of help/links pointing to the right direction would be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spree was written in a way to make it easy to replace the default search. There are a couple of examples of how to do it already written:

- https://github.com/romul/spree-solr-search
- [https://github.com/jbrien/spree_sunspot_search](https://github.com/jbrien/spree%5fsunspot%5fsearch)

We've also got a commercial product (http://spreecommerce.com/hub) that would make the data sync side of the integration easy, triggering updates in the system any time the data you're searching is updated.

Comment: Thank you, I followed spree_sunspot_search to write a custom implementation, and it works fine.